# Elevation from TIFF file

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation

I am new to QGIS. I have an Excel file with latitude & longitude points and a GeoTIFF (.tif) file. Now I want to get the elevation of all latitude & longitude points in the Excel file. How to do it with QGIS?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Save the Excel file as CSV
- In GIS, add the CSV file to QGIS using "Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer"
- Use "Sample raster values" from "Processing Toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T) > Raster Analysis".

You will get a layer containing elevation value. Now you can export it as Excel file.

I assume the GeoTiff file contains the elevation value of pixels.

Comment: yes, GeoTiff file contains elevation values.